# Why isn't context.auth appearing in the context:EventContext parameter on the Firebase function onCreate document trigger?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Problem: The optional context.auth.uid is expected to be part of the parameters of a firebase trigger, but is not being provided.

I am writing a document onCreate trigger on Firebase Cloud Functions. This trigger will write a sub-collection document using some of the data from the triggering document and the UID of the user who created it.

A standard trigger function will accept the following

```
export const onCreateUnit = functions.firestore.document('/units/{unitId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore.documentbuilder.html#oncreate

The context object should include an auth object which would contain the uid and token

```
context: {
    ...contextProperties,
    auth: {
        uid: XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX,
        token: YYYYYYYYYYY
    }
}
```

Some things to keep in mind.

1. This is an optional property
2. This property should be filled if a user is creating this document
3. All documents in the firestore database have a rule implemented protecting against non-users creating documents.
4. The client side is a React-Typescript project
5. The client is signed in to Firebase and waits for the onAuthStateChanged function to pass a user before creating documents.
6. No errors are thrown
7. The trigger function is confirmed to be called when the triggering document is created.
8. The context.auth property is undefined

Why is there no auth property provided in the context? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are not providing the data from the front-end to being with, check if your user is already logged in, happened to me couple of times.